# Favicon não aparece

Tags: php, favicon

Gerei o ícone no http://www.favicon-generator.org/

Colei o código que aparece no head depois da tag `<title>`.
E as imagens estão na raiz da pasta junto com o index.php

mas não aparece o ícone.

Alguém sabe o motivo?

Comment: Veja no Inspect Element do Chrome se realmente ele está pegando o caminho correto. Caso não esteja, o Inspect acusará erro no caminho.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione o código gerado para vermos se está ok.

Comment: Ou o link tá errado ou é cache

Comment: É o path mesmo, se eu coloco o caminho todo do localhost <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="http://localhost/site/apple-icon-57x57.png">, assim ele funciona, mas colocar o link na mão está errado né? o código original é <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve usar a seguinte linha para inserir um favicon:

```
<link rel="icon" href="../../images/favicon/image-32.png" sizes="32x32"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tente limpar o `cache`, também tenho esse tipo de problema.

Se não for cache é o caminho(path) que deve estar errado.

Comment: É o path mesmo, se eu coloco o caminho todo do localhost `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="http://localhost/site/apple-icon-57x57.png">`, assim ele funciona, mas colocar o link na mão está errado né? o código original é `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">`

Comment: Bacana.. que bom que conseguiu!