# Favicon não funciona no IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, favicon

Boa tarde a todos.Estou fazendo uns testes de layout HTML. Entrei no IE para ver como estava e reparei que o código `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/body/icon-amova.png"/>` não estava funcionando no IE 10.

Pesquisei em uns artigos:

https://tableless.com.br/favicons/

https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/360525-resolvido%C2%A0favicon-ico-n%C3%A3o-funciona/

E alterei meu código para

```
 <link rel="icon" href="img/body/icon-amova.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

Repare que alterei a extensão do arquivo e ele funciona perfeitamente nos outros navegadores, mas mesmo asssim, não funciona no IE 10.

Depois encontrei uma resposta aqui no SO

[Favicon não aparece](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64681/favicon-n%C3%A3o-aparece)

E alterei meu código para:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://localhost/amova/img/body/icon-amova.ico" type="image/x-icon" sizes="32x32"/>
```

Repare que usei o caminho completo, coloquei a tag `sizes`, limpei informações de cache. Mas nada mudou.

Alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Ja verificou se o caminho esta correto? Limpa o cache dos outros navegadores e vê se continua aparecendo

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno o caminho está correto pois nos outros navegadores está normal. Limpei o cache de todos os navegadores mas no IE não aparece.

Comment: Estou usando o xampp. Será que pode ser isso? Só no IE que não funciona.

Comment: Você tem certeza que é realmente um arquivo .ico? só renomear não basta

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno, o arquivo estava correto eu exportei pelo corel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque o seguinte código dentro da `<head>` do seu html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <link rel="icon" href="img/body/icon-amova.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/body/icon-amova.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Conteúdo do seu site...
    </body>
</html>
```

Sua imagem deverá ser realmente um arquivo `.ico` não basta apenas renomeá-lo.

Caso não funcione tente utilizar um arquivo `.png` no lugar do arquivo de ícone.

Comment: Vou testar aqui...

Comment: Funcionou... depois que coloquei os dois caminhos como você postou. Porque será que isso acontece? O IE é muito bugado.. mds

Comment: Eu acredito que para usar .ico você tem que usar rel="shortcut icon", mas não lembro exatamente como funciona. Depois faça alguns testes removendo apenas um link para ver se funciona.